# Setting retry_parameters on cron.yaml

Tags: google-app-engine, cron

I am setting up a cron job related to an App Engine app (standard environment, Python 3) and want it to retry after 2 minutes on failure. No matter what value I put in `retry_parameters` it seems to be retrying in 1 minute. Looking at the docs, I don't see a mention of a max wait time, so I wonder if I've just messed up the `cron.yaml` somehow.

Everything is working perfectly, except it is retrying sooner than I would like. Here's the yams — is this a limit or have messed something up.

`cron.yaml`:

```
cron:
- description: "daily call"
  url: /twilio/start_call/
  timezone: "America/Anchorage"
  schedule: every day 17:00
  retry_parameters:
    min_backoff_seconds: 120.0
    max_backoff_seconds: 360.0
    max_doublings: 3
```

**Edit:**

Here's a sample of the Stackdriver logs generated with the `cron.yaml`. The function returned 503 each time until the last and cron was firing the jobs at 1-minute intervals:

```
2018-11-26 17:00:00.764 AKST GET 503 178 B 970 ms AppEngine-Google (+http://code.google.com/appengine) /twilio/start_call/
2018-11-26 17:01:01.939 AKST GET 503 178 B 704 ms AppEngine-Google;(+http://code.google.com/appengine) /twilio/start_call/
2018-11-26 17:02:02.747 AKST GET 503 178 B 850 ms AppEngine-Google;(+http://code.google.com/appengine) /twilio/start_call/
2018-11-26 17:03:03.702 AKST GET 503 178 B 666 ms AppEngine-Google;(+http://code.google.com/appengine) /twilio/start_call/
2018-11-26 17:04:04.477 AKST GET 200 189 B 65 ms AppEngine-Google; (+http://code.google.com/appengine) /twilio/start_call/
```

Here's what a particular log entry looks like expanded:

```js
{
  httpRequest: {
    status: 503
  }
  insertId: "5bfca521000b366ac405955e"
  labels: {
    clone_id: "00c61b117cda9e441fb74ae3fd3225f528216a2a7e2fd701de97c95ac79fdc86ce3014f397"
  }
  logName: "projects/caller-app/logs/appengine.googleapis.com%2Frequest_log"
  operation: {
    first: true
    id: "5bfca52000ff0baa94727d8d2500016d7e7368656c7465722d63616c6c65720001323031383131323674313033313038000100"
    last: true
    producer: "appengine.googleapis.com/request_id"
  }
  protoPayload: {
    @type: "type.googleapis.com/google.appengine.logging.v1.RequestLog"
    appEngineRelease: "1.9.65"
    appId: "m~caller-app"
    cost: 1.9892999999999998e-8
    endTime: "2018-11-27T02:00:01.734682Z"
    finished: true
    first: true
    host: "caller-app.appspot.com"
    httpVersion: "HTTP/1.1"
    instanceId: "00c61b117cda9e441fb74ae3fd3225f528216a2a7e2fd701de97c95ac79fdc86ce3014f397"
    instanceIndex: -1
    ip: "0.1.0.1"
    latency: "0.970118s"
    megaCycles: "123"
    method: "GET"
    requestId: "5bfca52000ff0baa94727d8d2500016d7e7368656c7465722d63616c6c65720001323031383131323674313033313038000100"
    resource: "/twilio/start_call/"
    responseSize: "178"
    startTime: "2018-11-27T02:00:00.764564Z"
    status: 503
    taskName: "22a1b20373e6b0b93d21726ad7218cff"
    taskQueueName: "__cron"
    traceId: "54903137240fb57e546907087fb94ca5"
    traceSampled: true
    urlMapEntry: "auto"
    userAgent: "AppEngine-Google; (+http://code.google.com/appengine)"
    versionId: "20181126t103108"
  }
  receiveTimestamp: "2018-11-27T02:00:01.759151584Z"
  resource: {
    labels: {
      module_id: "default"
      project_id: "caller-app"
      version_id: "20181126t103108"
      zone: "us-west2-3"
    }
    type: "gae_app"
  }
  timestamp: "2018-11-27T02:00:00.764564Z"
  trace: "projects/caller-app/traces/54903137240fb57e546907087fb94ca5"
  traceSampled: true
}
```

Comment: A colleague has been testing it using the same cron.yaml that you posted and it worked properly for her. Can you show the logs that it generates in the Stackdriver logging?

Comment: Thanks for looking @RubénC. that's encouraging that maybe it's just something wrong  on my end rather than a system limitation. I've added a bunch of logging info. It shows the jobs running at 1-min intervals, I'm not sure what else is useful in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this was a simple case of mis-reading the documentation. But in case anyone misreads it as well…

Responding with a `503` is a special case. The documentation explains:

> By default, failed jobs are not retried unless a 503 status code is returned, in which case it is retried every minute until it succeeds or returns a 200-299 status code.

It doesn't explicitly say it, but this means that when the server responds with a `503` status the `retry_parameters` in `cron.yaml` are ignored and it still retries every minute.

Comment: nice catch, I missed it as well.